how do you fix the blender 4.1 open gl problem

i understand this issue but i do not know how to resolve this issue. can someone tell me how to do this? this happens during startup and then closes when i click OK.

Could you specify what graphics card you are using?

Qualcomm(R) Adreno(TM) 690 GPU. Ive never seen such display adapter and its been having problems with openGL since a windows update. i need to look in more to this graphics card. (EDIT: i just found out this is used for Phones rather of computers. which makes since because my computer BIOS is a Samsung but at the same time its really messed up. it works on 3.0 versions but i dont know why i doesnt want to work on 4.1)

i tried updating my driver but windows says its at the latest version for some reason

It appears that you might have tried to update your drivers from the Windows Control Panel Device Manager. Nothing wrong with that, but have you looked on your device manufacturer's website for drivers? Sometimes they will have various drivers and other updates that the other method doesn't catch.

Sorry, i dont know my device's manufacture. is it Samsung because thats the BIOS or is it AT&T because thats where it got shipped from according from the package

Blender changed the minimum OpenGL requirement for the 4.x versions: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ I don't know if anything on this page applies to your device, but here is a link to a Qualcomm software drivers site that I got from an Internet search: https://www.qualcomm.com/products/mobile/snapdragon/pcs-and-tablets/snapdragon-mobile-compute-platforms/snapdragon-8cx-gen-3-compute-platform#Software

well, i ran what seems to be a exe file. then i opened up 4.1, and the error is still there

@curious_1 so right now im about to contact the manufacture support, see if i can get some info off of it. i will keep you updated later
